# Joomla 3.2 - Akeeba Backup Failed on "nqkpb_faqbookpro_voting.MYD"

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm running backup on Joomla 3.2.4 using Akeeba Backup 4.7.3 but I got the below error while the process reaches 25%.

Can I disable that fabbookpro module as I'm not also using it at the moment?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Components -> Akeeba Backup, there is a Files and Directories Exclusion option where you can exclude files and directories from the backup.

Excluding the problem file should allow the backup to complete successfully.

Upgrading Akeeba Backup to [the latest recommended version](https://www.akeebabackup.com/compatibility.html) for your version of Joomla might also help.